# How to properly crop an image to fit imageview

Tags: android, image, crop, picasso

How do i crop an image that i use picasso with to properly fit the layouts parent width and a fixed height of e.g. 500 for both pictures taken in landscape mode and portrait mode. They may be scaled down or up, but without too great effect on the quality. A bit like how instagram fits their pictures in the scrolling view like squares. I need all pictures to fit the layouts width and a certain height.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
if(item.getTitle().equals("Add Picture")){
   verifyStoragePermissions(MainActivity.this);
   Intent loadPicture = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(loadPicture, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}
```

And

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loadPictureImageView);

            mlinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageScrollLayout);
            int width = mlinearLayout.getWidth();

            //Picasso.with(this).load(selectedImage).resize(width, 500).centerCrop().into(imageView);
            //Picasso.with(this).load(selectedImage).resize(width, 500).centerInside().into(imageView);
            Picasso.with(this).load(selectedImage).fit().into(imageView);

        }
    }
```

And my xml layout and imageview:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageScrollLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_layout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:id="@+id/loadPictureImageView"
                android:elevation="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `scaleType` attr through xml on the `ImageView` or use Picasso's built in image manipulation methods for determining scale and size.  A good tutorial can be found [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit).